# Using glide library, Show image in custom popup

Tags: android, image, popup, android-glide

I am using `RecyclerView` and `adapter`.
This is like this contact list.

If i clicked list, show Popup Dialog each contact image.

In `adapter`,

```
Popup popup = new Popup(mContext); 
final ImageView popupImv =(ImageView) popup.findViewById(R.id.imageView_custom);

Glide.with(mContext).load(photoUri)
  .signature(new StringSignature(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())))         
  .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(mContext))
  .into(popupImv);
```

But, error show

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass in a non null View

How can I do?

Comment: popupImv is null make sure (R.id.imageView_custom) is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are receiving is simply because "popupImv" is a null object. As a result, when you use "Glide" you receive this error.

I would suggest that you use AlertDialog instead of popup. Something like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder popupDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
ImageView popupImv = new ImageView(this);
Glide.with(mContext).load(photoUri)
                .signature(new StringSignature(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())))
                .bitmapTransform(new CropCircleTransformation(mContext))
                .into(popupImv);
popupDialogBuilder.setView(popupImv);
AlertDialog alertDialog = popupDialogBuilder.create();
alertDialogBuilder.show();
```